# getting timeout error while opening IE in Edge using selenium driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer

I am Trying to open our application from edge in IE mode but using selenium driver 4.8 and IE Driver also 4.8 using c#. But I am getting timeout error after 60 second. I am trying this on windows 10 but when same code i was trying on windows 19 it is woking fine.
Can you please help me in this how can i make it runnable on windows 10. I have mCafee installed on windows 10. is this blocking something?

Can you please help me in this ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUZNu.jpg)

application should be open edge in IE on both windows 10 and windows 19.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 0):

This timeout issue is usually caused by the protected mode settings even though you have already ignored the protected mode settings. There are 2 solutions:

1. Turn off protected mode of each zone in Internet Options
2. Use `InitialBrowserUrl` to directly visit the desired page, without waiting for redirection which could cause timeout error. Example: `ieOptions.InitialBrowserUrl = "https://www.bing.com";`